# How to append text to D3 Tooltips?

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I am having an issue with appending text to D3 tooltip. The code that generates the tooltip results in the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
```

The tooltip shows, but does not have any text. The following code is used to generate the tooltip:

1.Code where .toolTip is created

```
.toolTip {
position: absolute;
display: none;
min-width: 80px;
height: auto;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #6F257F;
padding: 14px;
text-align: center;
```

2.Code where variable is created.

```
 var tooltip = d3.select("body")
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "toolTip");
```

3. Code where attempt to append to node

   ```
   // Nodes
   d3.select('svg g.nodes')
   .selectAll('circle.node')
   .data(root.descendants())
   .enter()
   .append('circle')
   .classed('node', true)
   .attr('cx', function(d) {return d.x;})
   .attr('cy', function(d) {return d.y;})
   .attr('r', 4)
   .on("mousemove", function(d){
    tooltip
   .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 +"px")
   .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
   .style("display", "inline-block")
   .html(function (d) {return d.Name});
   })
   .on("mouseout", function(d){ tooltip.style("display", "none");});
   ```

Comment: Can you provide more information as to what the problem is? Is there an error generated? Does the tooltip fail to show, or show the wrong content, or is it located in the wrong place?

Comment: Error being generated is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined.  The tooltip does not fail, however the text within the tooltip( return d.Name) does not show. I can provide source code if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the function invoked on mousemove:

```
.on("mousemove", function(d){
   tooltip
    .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 +"px")
    .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
    .style("display", "inline-block")
    .html(function (d) {return d.Name});
})
```

In the first line, the `d` in function refers to the datum bound to the svg circle, while here: `.html(function(d) {`, the `d` refers to the datum bound to the tooltip. In this case the two `d`s do not refer to the same thing. You don't have any data bound to the tooltip, so this won't work - `d` here is undefined, hence your error message: "Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined."

Instead, just use the datum of the circle:

```
.on("mousemove", function(d){
   tooltip
    .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 +"px")
    .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
    .style("display", "inline-block")
    .html(d.Name); 
})
```

Whenever you see function(d) in a `.html` or `.attr` method of a d3 selection, you are accessing the datum of each element of the current selection. You don't want data associated with the tooltip, so you don't need to use `function(d)` in the `.html()` method, you've already accessed the datum you want in the first line.

---

It appears as though you are using a d3 hierarchical layout. This will alter the structure of your data, if you start with a form like:

```
 var data = { "name": "Parent", "children": [ 
    { "name": "Child A", "children": [ { "name": "Grandchild" } ] }, 
    { "name": "Child B", } 
    ] };
```

`d3.hierarchy(data)` will return an array with this structure:

```
[
 {data: Object, height: number, depth: number, parent: null, children: array[number], x: number, y: number},
 {data: Object, height: number, depth: number, parent: object, children: array[number], x: number, y: number},
  ... and so forth.
]
```

This is so there is one element in the data array for each node that is to be appended (selection.data() expects an array), and that each item in the data being passed to the selection has some properties that allow it to be positioned, connected, etc properly. The key point is that the original element in the data array is now at `d.data`. This is the same as with d3.pie or other layout generators - and avoids potential overlaps between property names (between original properties and properties created by the layout).

For you, the main result is your name won't reside at `d.Name`, but rather `d.data.Name` as this the data structure created by d3.hierarchy().

Comment: would it be possible to email code as trying to add edits to original post is not going through. Made changes to d.Name. however did not achieve success appending text to tooltip.

Comment: That is a bit odd - you should be able to edit your question. If unable, you could post a link to a fiddle, plunkr, or git repository in a comment. However, In the event function you could log d - the data structure of a d3 hierarchy (which I believe you are using) can be dirrerent than your original data, this will let you see that structure. I only have the phone at the moment, but will provide more info shortly.

Comment: The hierarchy changes the structure a bit, your data is now at d.data, so your name is now at d.data.Name. Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o3L7cywz/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have any data tied to the tooltip. Your code needs to be something like this:

```
var t = d3.select("body")
                .selectAll("div")
                .data(<your data>)
                .enter()
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "toolTip");
```

Now your div has data attached to it to iterate through.

Comment: You could just use the datum bound to the svg circle - no need to create new data as the data already exists.